PHP - сайт - переписать код на понятный
Дано, старый сайт написанный в процедурном стиле в том числе и работа с MYSQL.
Задача переписать и привести всё это в более понятный организованный код.
Общая мысль, сделать для начала для MYSQL какую-то функцию чтобы она обрабатывала все запросы, как бы из одного места, а не так как на сайте они раскиданы по файлам, то есть сделать что-то общего обработчика запросов ?
Что посоветуете ? Какие ещё могут быть моменты упрощения ?

Советую почитать книгу "Чистый код" Роберта Мартина, а также прочитать про подходы DRY, KISS....... а вообще можно тут набросить и паттерны проектирования и SOLID и много чего ещё.............а, ну и ООП

Чистый код - это когда сразу в процессор пишешь ) не думаю что нужно читать книгу чтобы переписать сайт небольшой старый сайт под более чуть современный вариант.

Мдаа.... прямо как в анекдоте   ............ если вы считаете так, то тогда удаляйте этот вопрос и оставляйте всё как есть, потому что очевидно вам это не нужно

И то, что я написал - это не "современный вариант" это адекватный вариант, который используют уже не одно десятилетие

Берете любой компонентный фреймворк. Небольшая структура навязывается уже самим фреймворком. Можете сами собрать только нужные компоненты без фреймворка. Тот же Active Record для быстрой работы с бд. Следующим этапом развития проекта будет как написал Алексей

отличные советы, в первом понятно, читать чтобы понять как надо и как не надо и то возможно там что-то уже устарело, второй  вариант, как превратить 10кб кода в 1 мегабайт и потом купить книгу, скачать мануал, как в этом мегабайте всё разгребать )

"привести всё это в более понятный организованный код" - тут стоило бы уточнить, ¿"понятный" кому? А то вы сделаете, как и предыдущий разработчик, код поятным себе, а следующий после вас будет снова страдать.

Я спрашиваю если не понятно то как сделали бы Вы, начали огранизовывать код, к примеру сначала работу SQL и так далее.

Вы боитесь подключить стороннюю библиотеку, чтобы не раздуть код до целого 1 мб? Вы серьезно? Но при этом пишите, что это небольшой старый сайт. Кажется, вы сами не знаете чего хотите. Потратить 1мб хранилища для того, чтобы облегчить понимание кода - это ничто в современном мире. "как в этом мегабайте всё разгребать )" - как раз все наоборот, легче найти специалиста на популярный фреймворк, чем на текущую вашу кашу

1 мб хранилища или кода - для изучения в случае непредвиденных ситуаций, спасибо, но, нет.

@webstackoverload "1 мб хранилища или кода - для изученияв случае непредвиденных ситуаций" --- если код организован "правильно" (а это именно то, чего вы и хотите) и каждый компонент занимается своей ответственностью (как в случае MVC, который указан в ответе и как написано в упомянутой мною книге и подходах) - то найти код значительно проще, т.к. всё разложено как раз по полочкам и вы знаете за что полочка отвечает. В тех же фреймворках идёт следование принципу как MVC (которое написано в ответе), так и разделению на эти самые полочки

@АлексейШиманский вы, как всегда вещаете в пространство. Вам бы на трибуну, на первомайскую демонстрацию. Вот так как раз очень пригодится умение говорить в целом правильные вещи, но при этом не имеющие никакого отношения к реальности. Но здесь, увы, это так не работает. Любой человек должен быть готов к восприятию той или иной информации. Если вы когда-нибудь открывали книгу  Роберта Мартина "Чистый код", то должны знать, что она предназначена для людей, которые уже имеют некоторый опыт программирования. Для тех, кто делает первые шаги, она будет непонятна и бесполезна

@webstackoverload "и то возможно там что-то уже устарело" --- вам не пишут читать книги 70-x годов. Вам написали те подходы, что как раньше, так и по сей день используют все для "понятного" кода, именно такого, что вы и хотите

@Ипатьев совершенно не согласен. Там есть аболютно понятные новичкам вещи. Например "называть переменные говоряще, а не a1,a2,a3". Разве это не ясно для начинающего? А "избегать остроумия" (типа не делайте методы вида eatMyShorts1)... что тут непонятного? А про отступы в коде,  а форматирование? А про то, что упорядочить функции можно например по близости контекста? ...Камон... Там именно что для новичков написано по факту... Который знает что такое функция и переменная.

Прочитал бегло, конечно есть дельные именно советы, что по коду то там всё индивидуально (мнение - опыт автора)

Все лучшие практики и приёмы - это результат чьего-либо опыта..... MVC из ответа - результат упорядочивания некоторого кода в результате опыта людей имеющих дело с кашей-хаосом в коде........ А вообще ваши выводы по поводу того или иного подхода или предолжени - просто смехотворны, не имея никакого нормального опыта сидите и рассуждаете о "это не подходит, то не подходит" ..... Почитайте про Эффект Даннинга — Крюгера. Это прям про вас

Алексей, Вы не можете утверждать о моём опыте, однако я могу сопостовлять даже свой малый опыт с тем что пишет вами рекомендуемый автор и по-моему могу ещё делать на фоне этого какае-то для себя выводы. Писать книги это одно и делать выводы со своей колокольни - почему бы и нет на то и пишут книги. Другое дело это реальные примеры как надо и как не надо на базе простых примеров которые поймёт даже уборщица.

Мысль правильная, но такое "одно место" должно быть не одно. Совсем в одном файле держать все запросы будет банально неудобно. Обычно их группируют по той сущности, с которой они работают - пользователь, товар, новость и так далее. Традиционно хотя и неправильно, такие файлы именуют "моделями".
Кроме этого очень желательно и весь HTML, выводимый на одной странице, так же вынести в отдельный файл.
И в итоге у вас получится архитектура MVC:

Запросы поользователей обрабатывает "контроллер" - тот файл, который у вас сейчас делает вообще всё. Сейчас же он будет получать и обязательно валидировать входящие данные, передавать их в "модель", получать ответ и инклюдить файл с HTML
Обработкой данных занимается "модель". В простейшем варианте это просто файл с функциями, которые возвращают нужные данные.
Выводом данных занимается файл с HTML, "представление" (view).

Так у вас получится аккуратная и расширяемая структура, с которой будет уже проще переходить на "настоящий" MVC, на основе фреймворка
Очень хорошо это всё расписано в книге Джона Дакетта PHP&HTML
Очень условно страница отображения одной новости может выглядеть так
<?php
require __DIR__.'init.php';
require __DIR__.'model/news.php';

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} else {
    http_response_code(404);
    die();
}

$data = news_get_one($db, $id);
if (!$data) {
    http_response_code(404);
    die();
}

require __DIR__.'template/news/item.php'

соответственно в model/news.php будут функции для получения/добавления данных, связанных с новостями, и в том числе
function news_get_one($db, $id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=?";
    return $db->execute_query($sql, [$id])->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

Подробнее про работу с БД в РНР можно почитать здесь
ну а в template/news/item.php будет что-то вроде
<?php require __DIR__."../layout_top.php" ?>
<h1><?= htmlspecialchars($data['title'])?></h1>
<div>
    <?= nl2br(htmlspecialchars($data['content']))?></h1>
</div>
<?php require __DIR__."../layout_bottom.php" ?>


Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
